# Gitlab push - rubygems error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gitlab

I am using gitlab as our local repository, but when i am pushing something into it, it tells me that i have something wrong with installed gems. I am not a Ruby programmer.

Do you have some tips on how to fix it?

Here is the problem:

```
remote: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:39:in
`eval_gemfile': Gemfile syntax error compile error (Bundler::GemfileError)
remote: on line 23: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
remote: gem "mysql2", group: :mysql
remote:                     ^
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:10:in `evaluate'
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:26:in `build'
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler.rb:153:in `definition'
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
```

I tried to re-install all gems, but nothing changed. Do you have some tips, where the problem is?

Comment: If you are not [a] rubby programmer, are a slippery programmer?

Comment: Please attach your Gemfile

Comment: here it is http://paste.debian.net/112351/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're running the code with Ruby >= 1.9. This hash syntax is not supported in older versions.

Comment: I am using ruby 2.1.2p95